# Mock in the Middle with C++/Gmock

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googlemock

I have a class A that instantiates an object of class B in its constructor. I want to test A with a mock object of B.

And no, I can not pass object of B as a parameter. Is there any other way?

I saw an article http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-mocktest/index.html, with "Mock in the Middle" as the interesting topic, but that is in Java. Is it possible in C++?

```
class B {...};

class A {
  private:
    B* b;

  public:
    A() {
        b = new B();
    }
    ~A() {..}
};
```

EDIT:

In general, the object may be created in some other method, on demand. For example,

```
class A {
    ...
    int doSomething() {
        // Create an object of class B
        b = new B();
    }
};
```

Comment: can you create a new constructor take b?

Comment: I could, but this is one of the examples where the object is created inside the class. In general, the objects can be created on demand, for example, in a method. But this is good point, let me edit the question to make it more clear.

Comment: sounds like you need factory object/function

Comment: Add a constructor with a factory for your B object (or anywhere you need it) and mock that as you want

Comment: Could you give an example for this? Because if I am taking factory as an argument in constructor, then the place where A is instantiated needs to instantiate that factory too, and that is the whole thing I am trying to avoid.

Comment: But I do agree that both these points combined solve the general case problem as well.

Comment: another idea off the top of my head: you could just add code to call a friend factory for that object and modify the B object by switching it with another one. It would be minimally invasive and won't modify the calling locations for A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use factory pattern

---

given this code

```
class B {
  public:
    virtual std::string name() { return "B::name"; }
    virtual ~B() {}
};

class A {
  private:
    std::unique_ptr<B> b;

  public:
    A() {}
    void createB() {
        b.reset(new B); // you want to replace `new B` with something else right?
    }
    void print() {
        std::cout << (b ? b->name() : std::string()) << std::endl;
    }
    ~A() {}
};
```

---

with factory function

```
class A {
  private:
    std::unique_ptr<B> b;

  public:
    std::function<std::unique_ptr<B>()> b_maker;

    A() {
        // default maker
        b_maker = []{ return std::unique_ptr<B>(new B); };
    }

    A(std::function<std::unique_ptr<B>()> func) {
        b_maker = func;
    }

    void createB() {
        b = b_maker();
    }

    void print() {
        std::cout << (b ? b->name() : std::string()) << std::endl;
    }
    ~A() {}
};
```

create A with default B is same

```
A();
```

and now you can supply mocked B with

```
A([]{return std::unique_ptr<B>{new MockedB};});
```

[live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d2e953a13ba3f899)

---

you can also make `b_maker` to be a global variable so you don't need to pass it around (but I don't recommended to to it)

---

you can do it with the complicated way with `AbstractBFactory`, `BFactory`, `MockBFactory`, but it is too much overhead and looks like Java...

Comment: Looks like I'll have to end up doing something like this. Thanks for the code.